# How To implement Quickblox video chat

Tags: android, quickblox, videochat

I want to integrate quickblox videochat in my android application , but i am unable to find proper documentation, i had gone through quickblox website but it's not helpful and not easy to understand , if anyone help i will be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to enable signaling. Using below code, your ability to do call or receive the call.

```
QBRTCClient.getInstance(context).prepareToProcessCalls();
QBChatService.getInstance().getVideoChatWebRTCSignalingManager()
                .addSignalingManagerListener(new QBVideoChatSignalingManagerListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void signalingCreated(QBSignaling qbSignaling, boolean createdLocally) {
                        if (!createdLocally) {
                            QBRTCClient.getInstance(context).addSignaling((QBWebRTCSignaling) qbSignaling);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Then, you need to add session callback that helps you incoming calls

```
QBRTCClient.getInstance(context).addSessionCallbacksListener(this);
```

Now, it overrides one of *onReceiveNewSession*, In this method, you will receive a call when an opponent is a call to you.

**To place a call,**

```
 QBRTCTypes.QBConferenceType qbConferenceType = QB_CONFERENCE_TYPE_VIDEO;
 List<Integer> opponents = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 opponents.add(userid); //12345 - QBUser ID
 //Set user information
 Map<String, String> userInfo = new HashMap<>();
 userInfo.put("key", "value");
  //Init session
  QBRTCSession session = QBRTCClient.getInstance(this).createNewSessionWithOpponents(opponents, qbConferenceType);
 //Start call
 session.startCall(userInfo);
```

**To accept a call**

```
@Override
    public void onReceiveNewSession(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession) {
       qbrtcSession.acceptCall(qbrtcSession.getUserInfo());
    }
```

Comment: i am getting error while addiing quickblox dependency , error : -Program type already present: org.webrtc.CameraEnumerationAndroid$CaptureFormat
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: org.webrtc.CameraEnumerationAndroid$CaptureFormat, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

Comment: its too lengthy , how i can share my code , i just added quickblox dependency :  implementation "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc:3.7.0"  and getting above error

Comment: sharing only build. gradle files (project & app module) will be enough to guide me on the issue.

Comment: its not possible to send all gradle code in comment, Do you know any other option ?

Answer (score 0):

**Getting Error**  -Program type already present: org.webrtc.CameraEnumerationAndroid$CaptureFormat Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: org.webrtc.CameraEnumerationAndroid$CaptureFormat, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

**THIS IS MY APP LEVEL GRADLE**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mindinfo.xchangemall.xchangemall"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard- 
rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'

androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev295-1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.util.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar- 
library:0.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

implementation 'com.github.stfalcon:multiimageview:0.1'
implementation 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9'
implementation 'com.github.midorikocak:currency-picker-android:1.1.9'
implementation 'com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.futuremind.recyclerfastscroll:fastscroll:0.2.5'
implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
implementation "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc:3.8.1"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

**THIS IS MY PROJECT LEVEL GRADLE:-**

```
buildscript {
//    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
//    ext.roomVersion = '1.0.0'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
   jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/' }

    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
    maven { url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HyphenateInc/Hyphenate-        
 SDK-Android/master/repository" }

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'


}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk- 
releases/raw/master/"
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
    maven { url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HyphenateInc/Hyphenate- 
 SDK-Android/master/repository" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```